# How to get the suffix of a int variable in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a int variable in which I am storing the integer value. Now I want to get only the suffix. e.g:

```
int num = 12;
int num = 17;
etc
```

from the above num variables, I want to store the suffix like 2, 7 etc.

What is the efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Something like `int suffix = num % 10;`?

Comment: num%10 % is mod operator

Comment: What do you want for `int num = 0x10`? (getting `0` for this is very hard)

Comment: @amitkumar your problem is limited to two digit numbers or suffix can be of more digits?

Comment: Is your question _"How can I get the last digit of the decimal representation of a number?"_ ? If yes, then the first comment is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The modulo (`%`) gives you the remainder when divided by a number which will be 10.

```
int num1 = 12;
int num2 = 17;
int suffix1 = num1 % 10;
int suffix2 = num2 % 10;
```